# Quantificational Logic: "For every number a, the equation $ax^2 + 4x -2 = 0$ has at least one solution if and only if $a \ge -2$."

Tags: logic, proof-verification, quantifiers

This is a solution check for my quantified representation of the following statement.

"For every number a, the equation $ax^2 + 4x -2 = 0$ has at least one solution if and only if $a \ge -2$."

$\forall a[$iff $a \ge -2$ there exists at least one solution such that $ax^2 + 4x -2 = 0]$

$\forall a[(a \ge -2) \leftrightarrow \exists x(ax^2 + 4x -2 = 0)]$

Comment: Wow, I absolutely mangled this one, sorry. Edited the title and content to reflect the real statement.

Comment: Yep that's correct.